# Generating Function for for the given $1,1,0,1,1,1.....$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

what is the generating function for the sequence $1,1,0,1,1,1...... $

My answer is

$$s=1+x+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+.....
   =(1+x)+\dfrac1{1-x}$$

kinda confused

Comment: Do you mean $s=1+x+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+\cdots$?

Comment: The second summand has to be multiplied with $x^3$

Comment: ...  or the first summand on the right-hand side should be deleting the missing term, "$-x^2$".

Comment: @EricTowers This is even better. Did not notice this possibility.

Comment: @EricTowers thanks

Comment: It seems like $s = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n - x^2$.

Comment: It is not clear what the pattern is. Do we continue with
$$
1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0\ldots ?
$$